# Android clear backstack when leaving item tab BottomNavigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-bottom-nav-view

I am using the last navigation library (version 2.4.0) which include multiple backstacks with a bottom navigation view.

The default behavior is that each backstack is saved when user go back to a tab.
I want to clear a backstack when the user leave a tab.

Based on this bottom nav with 3 tabs :

| Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ScreenA1 | ScreenB1 | ScreenC1 |
| ScreenA2 | ScreenB2 | ScreenC2 |

From Tab1, if user:

- go to ScreenA2
- clic on Tab2 (ScreenB1 displayed)
- go back to Tab1
- here I want ScreenA1 and not ScreenA2 (default behavior of navigation library)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can turn off multiple backstacks for tabs, as it was before lib version 2.4. For this you should change

```
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

to

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController, false)
```

Comment: Saved me after decades of pure agony. No sure why this is not the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your navigation file add these properties `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive` to the action which navigates to ScreenA2.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_A1_to_A2"
    app:destination="@id/A2"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/A1"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

for more information look at this link:
[popUpTo example: circular logic](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop-example)

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this solution is that if I press back I lost the fragment (and I don't want it)

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the below before you invoke the method to navigate to TAB1.

> navController.popBackStack(R.id.ScreenA1, false);

This worked for me wherein I had a similar scenario to you.

Comment: Please use a comment for the non-answering part I deleted.

Comment: Please also remind that using other options as a workaround to your account limitation is not allowed. You will unlock the comment option at 50 reputations).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32207737)

Answer (score -1):

I just done by onNavigationItemSelected Listener

1. The id in your navigation.xml and menu.xml should be different
2. When you handle the click action for particular item, try this

   ```
            R.id.home_bottom_item -> {navController.popBackStack();
            navController.navigate(R.id.home_bottom_item)
        }
   ```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working.